# How can I wrap/proxy a namespace?

Tags: c#

I have an internal NuGet package that wraps  a 3rd party NuGet package which in turn wraps an API. My internal wrapper handles authentication and a few other convenience elements.

The wrapped package includes typed namespaces - `Wrapped.Package.V1.*` - and updates fairly frequently. Right now, we have to update the NuGet package on all of the apps that use the wrapper (which will necessarily continue to happen), but we also have to spend "busy work" time updating all of the `using` statements through out the dependent apps.

I'm looking for something that my wrapper package can offer so that the dependent apps don't have to hit all the `using`s, and will just see compiler errors if the underlying package changes signatures that they rely on.

That is: I'd like my wrapper package to provide something like a `Wrapper.WrappedPackage.Current.*` set of namespaces that automagically point to the version of the wrapped package that my wrapper wraps.

It's okay if this is an opt-in thing on the part of the dependent apps. I'm not trying to *hide* anything, just remove some of the busywork.

Writing a code generator to emit a shim is a possibility, but a daunting one; I'm hoping that there's something a bit more maintainable.

I'd prefer something that automagically handles modifications to the namespaces, but having to do a little copy-pasta (or write a generator that does some magic for the namespaces themselves without having to shim all of the classes) would work, too.

I've tried Googling around this, but "using" and "proxy" are ... rather general terms (lots of hits for proxying HTTP requests), so the results have been disappointing.

Based on the comments, I feel I need to clarify a bit.

I have a base package that exposes half a dozen namespaces, each of which have possibly dozens of descendants (mostly classes). Specifically, `Wrapped.Namespace.V1.*`. Consumers of *my* package might use any of those, some in a `using static` context (eg., `Wrapped.Namespace.V1.Enums`; it's not uncommon to add `using static Wrapped.Namespace.V1.Enums.TypeEnum` alongside several related enums).

What I would like to do is add something in my wrapper package that "hides" `Wrapped.Namespace.V1` behind `Consonto.WrappedCurrent` so that consumers of my package can add `using Consonto.WrappedCurrent.X` or `using static Consonto.WrappedCurrent.Enums.TypeEnum`, that `WrappedCurrent` will always refer to the current version that the package is wrapping.

Or, replace

```
using Wrapped.Namespace.V1.X;
using static Wrapped.Namespace.V1.Enums.TypeEnum;
using Example = Wrapped.Namespace.V1.Bar;
```

with

```
using Consonto.WrappedCurrent.X;
using static Consonto.WrappedCurrent.Enums.TypeEnum;
using Example = Consonto.WrappedCurrent.Bar;
```

I fully recognize that upgrading a consumer might still require further modification when the underlying package's contracts change radically; I'm just trying to reduce the busy-work of having to upgrade the NuGet package *and* running a global find-and-replace of `Wrapped.Namespace.V1.` to `Wrapped.Namespace.V2.` (then having to remember that one weird place that needs to be updated to "V2" but doesn't use the full namespace for some reason).

Comment: Would [namespace aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias) help?

Comment: If I can export them, yes. If the consumers of my package need to do that themselves, I don't think so; I think they'd still need to update all of the same classes.

Comment: Depending on how extensively the namespace is imported, consider a `global using` so that you can update it in one place. (More extensive = more feasible. You don't want a `global using` for a rarely-imported namespace.)  Individual usings are redundant but not an error, so you can remove those progressively leading up to the first update of the `global using` if you don't want to do it all at once.

Comment: @madreflection: Possibly, though that doesn't proxy `using static`s, which would be desirable. Basically, I want to be able to do a one-time global find-and-replace for "Wrapped.Stuff.V1" to "Consonto.WrappedStuff.Current" and have the only "V1" reference anywhere in the codebase live in my wrapper.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can do `global using static`, as well.